# SQL Query Recent Record

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

Good afternoon,

I've been working on this all day and I can't figure it out. I'm performing this query in excel.

```
SELECT 
PRICE_BOOK.status,
PRICE_BOOK.ms_code,
PRICE_BOOK.location_code,
SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR.name,
PRICE_BOOK.mfg_code,
PRICE_BOOK.group_code,
PRICE_BOOK.stock_id,
PRICE_BOOK.effective_date,
PRICE_BOOK.price
FROM dbo.MS_INFO MS_INFO, dbo.PRICE_BOOK PRICE_BOOK, dbo.SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR 
SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR
WHERE MS_INFO.ms_code = PRICE_BOOK.ms_code AND 
SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR.location_code = PRICE_BOOK.location_code AND 
((PRICE_BOOK.mfg_code Not In ('Type1','Type2','Type3')))
```

This is exporting the prices for each location, product, effective time, and price.

But, I need only the most recent "PRICE_BOOK.effective_date" per unique combination of ms_code, location_code, name, mfg_code, group_code, stock_id.

In other words, I need to export only the most recent price per product per location.

`status ms_code location_code   name    mfg_code    group_code  stock_id    effective_date   price 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  61  7/5/17 0:01  1.09 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  61  7/4/17 0:01  1.41 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #2 PartType1   Group1  61  7/3/17 0:01  1.76 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #2 PartType1   Group1  61  5/24/17 0:01     1.20 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  62  7/5/17 0:01  1.67 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  62  7/4/17 0:01  1.19 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  62  7/3/17 0:01  1.14 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  62  5/24/17 0:01     1.11 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  63  7/5/17 0:01  1.33 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  63  7/4/17 0:01  1.59 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  63  7/3/17 0:01  1.61 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  63  5/24/17 0:01     1.75 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  7/5/17 0:01  1.75 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  7/4/17 0:01  1.77 
A   Supplier2   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  7/3/17 0:01  1.45 
A   Supplier2   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  5/24/17 0:01     1.77`

Expected Results

`status ms_code location_code   name    mfg_code    group_code  stock_id    effective_date   price 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  61  7/5/17 0:01  1.09 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #2 PartType1   Group1  61  7/3/17 0:01  1.76 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  62  7/5/17 0:01  1.67 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  63  7/5/17 0:01  1.33 
A   Supplier1   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  7/5/17 0:01  1.75 
A   Supplier2   Terminal 1  City #1 PartType1   Group1  64  7/3/17 0:01  1.45`

Edit: Changed query per Clock's comment

```
SELECT
PRICE_BOOK.status,
PRICE_BOOK.ms_code,
PRICE_BOOK.location_code,
SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR.name,
PRICE_BOOK.mfg_code,
PRICE_BOOK.group_code,
PRICE_BOOK.stock_id,
PRICE_BOOK.effective_date,
PRICE_BOOK.price
FROM dbo.PRICE_BOOK PRICE_BOOK
    INNER JOIN dbo.SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR
        ON SUPPLIER_LOC_HDR.location_code = PRICE_BOOK.location_code
WHERE ((PRICE_BOOK.mfg_code Not In ('Type1','Type2','Type3')))
```

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

Comment: Can you provide your schema with some data to write and test query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column).  Welcome to [tag:greatest-n-per-group], where other RDBMSs have utilities to help you.  Also, drop the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, and use explicit `JOIN`s and accompanying conditions instead.

Comment: Clockwork, sorry I’m not a programmer. Not understanding what you said. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use window function. Something like this:

```
qualify row_number() over(partition by product, location order by effective_date desc) = 1
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't exist on MySQL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: Pre General Availability Draft

Comment: When I googled I tried that and over didn’t work in excel I think